# How to change column identify from sequence to GENERATED ALWAYS with data

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

as my title, I want to change my identity column by sequence to GENERATED ALWAYS.

For ex, I have a table like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE DPT.Deposit_SEQ 
START WITH     1
INCREMENT BY   10
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;

CREATE TABLE DPT.TEST(
Id NUMBER(10)DEFAULT DPT.Deposit_SEQ.nextval NOT NULL
,Code VARCHAR2(20),
CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
Insert into DPT.TEST (ID, CODE) values (1,'ABC');
COMMIT;
```

Now, I want to change from sequence to GENERATED ALWAYS like this:

```
Id NUMBER(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH 6
INCREMENT BY   10
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

I tried by create one more column and drop old column but failed. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"But failed" is not an Oracle error and is difficult to debug.

Anyway, it works for me:

Create table and a sequence, insert some rows:

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE Deposit_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 10 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE TEST
  2  (
  3     Id    NUMBER (10) DEFAULT Deposit_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
  4     Code  VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO TEST (ID, CODE)
  2       VALUES (1, 'ABC');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO TEST (ID, CODE)
  2       VALUES (3, 'DEF');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

        ID CODE
---------- --------------------
         1 ABC
         3 DEF
```

Drop current primary key column (`ID`) and add a new, identity column:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE test
  2     DROP COLUMN id;

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE test
  2     ADD id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH 6;

Table altered.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

CODE                         ID
-------------------- ----------
ABC                           6
DEF                           7

SQL> ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT pk_test PRIMARY KEY (id);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

As you can see, no problem.